# Link not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, firefox, razor

I have a Asp.net MVC3 application where in some of the Links rendred don't work in FIREFOX, while the same works well in IE.

I have created a sample application for showing the issue ( https://www.dropbox.com/s/zvkwp1spl05nmeh/FireFox_Issue.zip )

In this application, I have  3 pages: **Main** page, **Second** page and **Third** page.

Here **Third** page is **rendered** using **Ajax** on page load of **Second** page. After that you will find the **Report Link** is rendered, but doesn't work.

Could not understand why its **not working** in **FIREFOX**, whereas same works in **IE**

Comment: Make a live working example, even if it is on jsfiddle, people don't like downloading .zips.

Also, chances are if it works on IE but not firefox, its not working as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't run your sample code but often times when this happens to me, is because I have some overlaying element like a `div` on top of the links that don't work.

You should make a live example of your problem, that would help a ton.

Comment: The example is live only. Layout and css is exactly the same what I have in my application. Plz take a look at it. Thanx.

Comment: Adding overflow:hidden fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to RCorrie. Problem fixed.

Below is the solution, if anyone is searching for this issue:

The issue was with css style I was using:

```
.rightDiv
{
    position: relative;
    **overflow:hidden;**
}
```

Adding **overflow:hidden** fixed the issue.